# Creating another output device in iOS application with different content

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, output

> NOTE : Kindly Look into the **Edit Section** , This section is just a
>   Reference purpose.

I'm new to the IOS App Development architecture . Please, I just need a clarification that whether is it possible to make two outputs , one is continuously running in a background connecting to some other Output device (HDTV, Monitor, etc.) as shown in this link  [here](http://learninginhand.com/blog/5-ways-to-show-your-ipad-on-a-projector-screen.html)

For example, I'm giving a seminar with connecting projector, running my Presentation as background process at the same time I can manipulate my stuff at laptop screen by using "EXTEND Mode".

Please don't de-promote my question, I just need to know whether "IOS Development Architecture" providing this or not .?
Need to Do:

1) Possible to do with another Output screens with Background process(Continuously whenever  a MyApp is alive).

2) One foreground display in my iPad that is intractable of MyApp.

---

**Edit :**
**Update To my own Question :**

For the above mentioned problem,

> I got the solution something interesting [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html) and [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ExternalDisplay/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010724).

I'll go through it, But If anyone has idea OR overcome from this problem, Please suggest me some helpful information.

**Brief Explanation about Problem :**

I just want to show some different content in another output device which has connected to iPad, when my App is running .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using AirPlay.

By default, when you connect an external display to your iPad or iPhone, you get a mirrored image of your app on the external screen.  But, you can access the second screen from your iPad or iPhone application and use it for other content. You can get all the available "screens" through the `UIScreen` class. From the docs for `[UIScreen screens]`:

> The returned array includes the main screen plus any additional screens connected to the device. The main screen is always at index 0.
>
> Not all devices support external displays. Currently, external displays are supported by iPhone and iPod touch devices with Retina displays and iPad. Older devices, such as the iPhone 3GS do not support external displays. Connecting to an external display requires an appropriate cable between the device and display.

For examples on what you can do, you can check out Real Racing 2, who shows a map on the iPad and the actual race on the external screen; or [Tweetwall](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tweetwall/id642832782?mt=8) which also uses this approach (disclosure: I was responsible in part for making Tweetwall).

**EDIT**: You can initialize the external screen like this:

```
// Get second screen
UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
secondScreen.currentMode = secondScreen.preferredMode;

// Get the screen's bounds so that you can create a window of the correct size.
CGRect screenBounds = CGRectMake(secondScreen.bounds.origin.x,
                                 secondScreen.bounds.origin.y,
                                 secondScreen.currentMode.size.width,
                                 secondScreen.currentMode.size.height);
    
UIWindow *secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
secondWindow.screen = secondScreen;
 
// Setup external view controller
YourExternalScreenViewController *extVC = [[YourExternalScreenViewController alloc] init];
// Set VC for second window
secondWindow.rootViewController = extVC;
// Show the window.
secondWindow.hidden = NO;
```

There's a little bit more legwork, but this is the concept.

**EDIT 2**: And here is a link to [Apple's Multiple Display Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Hi, do you know how to animate some elements(ex: UIlabel Text with animation) in the external Display. I've tried using main thread as well . but no luck. the result is getting but animation effect not  .

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Airplay server** if you want to mirror your mobile output on the screen.

Comment: I don't want duplicate display . Please understand the question...I just need to make in app. I need to know that, whether possible or not?

Comment: No,on the basis of my experience till now i don't think its possible.